# conversion from Text String to Date in R

Tags: r

I have a column of text dates in the format of Feb20, Mar20, ... Feb21, I would like to create a new column with properly formatted dates as in Feb/20, Mar/20... etc.  What is the easiest way doing this?  I need this to create my ggplot.

thank you in advance!

Comment: `as.Date(paste0("01",x$date),format="%d%b%y")`

Answer (score 0):

if locale-setting is an issue, try

```
mystr <- c("Feb20", "Mar20")

#store current locale, en change
orig_locale <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
#create dates
ans <- as.POSIXct( paste0( "01", mystr), format = "%d%b%y" )
#set locale top previous
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", orig_locale)
#format datse to whatever you like
format(ans, format = "%b/%y")
```